# Need help finding the equation of a cubic polynomial

Tags: functions, polynomials

I need help finding the equation of a real cubic polynomial that cuts the x-axis at 1/2 and -3, has a y-intercept of 30, and passes through (1, -20).

So far I have a(2x-1)(x+3)(bx-c)?

Is there a way to solve directly to the factored form? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you use the fact that the $y$-intercept is $20$?  How would you use the fact that is passes through $(1,-20)$?  Also, why do you have both $a$ and $b$ -- $a$ can be absorbed into the third factor, leaving only two parameters.  Finally, in what was is what you have written not already written directly in factored form?

Answer (score 1):

Write $p(x)=a(x-0.5)(x+3)(x-b)$. Now we have two equations:
$p(0)=30 \implies 1.5ab=30 \implies ab=20 \implies b=\frac{20}{a} $ and 
$p(1)=-20 \implies 2a(1-b)=-20 \implies 2-2b=-b$